# Getting Updated JTable Values

Tags: java, swing, jtable, tablecelleditor, defaulttablemodel

I'm trying to use a JTable in order to update users in a Java SWING application, currently when I edit a cell the results of the edit can only be obtained if I click a different cell thus firing the tableModelListener. I want to be able to get these changed values on a button event without clicking other cells.

My table definitions:

```
DefaultTableModel tableModel = new DefaultTableModel();

table = new JTable(tableModel);

tableModel.addColumn("Key");
tableModel.addColumn("Value");

if (PatientView.getSelected() != null){
    tableModel.addRow(new Object[]{"Name", PatientView.getSelected().getName()});
    tableModel.addRow(new Object[]{"Age", PatientView.getSelected().getAge()});
    tableModel.addRow(new Object[]{"Height", PatientView.getSelected().getHeight()});
    tableModel.addRow(new Object[]{"Weight", PatientView.getSelected().getWeight()});
    tableModel.addRow(new Object[]{"BMI", PatientView.getSelected().getCalculatedBMI()});

}
```

Table Listener

```
tableModel.addTableModelListener(new TableModelListener(){
            @Override
            public void tableChanged(TableModelEvent arg0) {
                int row = arg0.getFirstRow();
                int column = arg0.getColumn();
                Object data = tableModel.getValueAt(0, 1);
                System.out.println(data);
            }
        });
```

Button Action Listener

```
okButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                        Vector data = tableModel.getDataVector();
                        System.out.println(table.getValueAt(0, 1));
                        System.out.println(data);
                    }
                });
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I want to be able to get these changed values on a button event without clicking other cells.

See [Table Stop Editing](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/12/12/table-stop-editing/).